# mysql query is not working i had many try

Tags: php, mysql

this is mysql query that i wanted to store date and time whenever a user come and 
post comments over my website. But it showing me this context:

```
"Parse error: syntax..
code'error, unexpected 'now' (T_STRING) in"
$qry1='insert into life(title,quotation,photos,datetime) values('.$title.','.$quotation.','.$vphoto.''now())';'
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. It will also help avoid syntax errors like this.

Comment: why every time you block my account to post a questions

Comment: No-one here is going to know that. I don't even know if it's done by humans. Possibly your questions are getting excessive downvotes and need to be improved? Hard to know, I assume they've been deleted?

Comment: Anyway regarding your actual problem here I suggest you make a basic study of the use of quote marks to build strings in both PHP and MySQL as this is quite a simple syntax error caused by PHP thinking the single quote marks inside your query are actually marking the end of the PHP string. And also, you could avoid it anyway by using proper, safe, parameterised queries. Again, if you haven't studied that, now would be a good time to go and do so.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using PHP. When running queries, you should make use of prepared statements as it comes with a lot of benefits such as:

1. Reduced parsing time in that the preparation of your query is done only once.
2. SQL injection prevention.

   ```
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   // Check that your connection was successful
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   // prepare and bind
   $qry1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO life (title, quotation, photos, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
   $qry1->bind_param("sss", $title, $quotation, $vphoto);

   // set parameters and execute
   $title = "Lorem Ipsum";
   $quotation = "Lorem Ipsum";
   $vphoto = "lorem@ipsum.com";

   $qry1->execute();
   $qry1->close();

   $conn->close();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In php if you are using single quote 'x' then inside this you have to usedouble quote " " . Like this
$q =  ' xyz("djch")' to maintain the escape sequence.

For your query you should use the curly braces to wrap the variables in php.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO life (v1,v2,v3) VALUES ('{$v1}','{$v2}','{$v3}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store the current time just use MYSQL's functions.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES (now())");
```

If you need to use PHP to do it, the format it Y-m-d H:i:s so try

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$date')");
```

your Code:

```
$qry1='insert into life(title,quotation,photos,datetime) values('.$title.','.$quotation.','.$vphoto.''now())';'
```

change to this:

```
$qry1="insert into life(title,quotation,photos,datetime) values('.$title.','.$quotation.','.$vphoto.', now())';'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. You have misused single quotes and concatenation.

```
$qry1 = "INSERT INTO life ( title, quotation, photos, datetime ) VALUES('$title', '$quotation', '$vphoto', NOW())";
```

**Note:** Your query is wide open to *Sql Injections*. Learn about [prapared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score -1):

$qry1='insert into life(title,quotation,photos,datetime) values("'.$title.'","'.$quotation.'","'.$vphoto.'", now())';

try above code if you use single codes on values('.$title .') compiler will thing start point of query is near 'insert AND end point is near 'title